# How to write a query to select a word within a list?

Tags: ms-access

I have a table with a column named "Tag" which contains "Tags" (stored as text, separated by a forward slash) e.g. `QR1 / QR11b / QR12` or `QR1 / QR2`

How do I write a query which just displays records containing the value `QR1` within the list of Tags

I am using Access 2013 and have very limited knowledge of SQL

I have tried using `="QR1"` but this doesn't work

I have also tried using `Like "*QR1*"` but this doesn't work as it also finds records relating to `QR11b` and `QR12`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is poor database design, and you really should store your list in a separate table. However, you can write the query.

Include the delimiter or word boundry in your like:

```
MyField = "QR1" OR MyField Like "QR1 /*" OR MyField Like "*/ QR1" OR MyField Like "*/ QR1 /*"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure, that before and after every Tag is always a SPACE, you can use the LIKE keyword - If the first and last Tag have no Space before/after it, use this:

```
WHERE ((" " & Field & " ") LIKE "* QR1 *"
```

And if you are not sure that there is a SPACE before and after, you can use this:

```
WHERE ((" " & Replace(FIELD,"/"," / ") & " ") LIKE "* QR1 *"
```

This seems complicated and could take (a little) more time to process, but you have the benefit of having to write the searched tag only once. (=les Error prone, easier to change.